# About initializing registers

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers

I am new to Assembly Language programming and I am working on a dosbox application.

My question is that when we write any program in Assembly Language, do we have to initialise the general purpose registers as we use to initialise the variables in C# programming?

Can we initialize the ax register in AL as:

```
mov ax,0?
```

Comment: If your program doesn't use a register then no need to initialize it. If you do need a register and it needs to have a specific value (even zero) then you need to set that yourself. Depending on whether you create an EXE or COM program some of the registers at program start may have values written to them that mean something. You can look at the notes for EXE and COM program register values at start up for a good description: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/51/29.html

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply. But can we only initialize a general purpose register using zero or we can initialize it using other values as well?       Also can we initialize a variable using a data from a specific memory location?

Comment: Sir why do you think their would not be a use of any register in a program as without using general purpose register ,we won't be able to perform certain task using CPU. I am actually talking about 8086 microprosssor which uses 16-bit registers .

Comment: You can initialize a register to any value you wish (including zero). Some programs do not use all of the registers. Some may only use a few. You don't have to initialize registers your program may not use. If your program (for example) uses AX, BX, SI, DI then you don't have to initialize the registers CX, DX, BP. You **can** read a value from memory to initialize a register.

Comment: `mov ax, 1234` works with no dependency on the old value, just like in C# you can write `int var = 1234` without having to zero it first.

Answer (score 3):

`mov ax, 1234` works with no dependency on the old value, just like in C# you can write an `x = 1234` assignment without having to zero it first.

Registers exist forever, it's not exactly creating a new storage location like `int foo = 1234`, but it can be helpful to think about the first write to a register as initializing the local variable you're *using* that register to hold.

Every instruction has a fixed effect on the architectural state (register and memory contents), like a state machine.  It doesn't matter how you got to the current state; the effect of `mov ax, 1234` is *always* to overwrite the previous value of `ax` so it holds `1234`, aka `0x04d2`, aka the binary bit pattern that represents both those numbers.

If you wanted to sum an array, you might `mov ax, 0` before a loop that used `add ax, [si]` / `add si,2`, because that's one way to implement the same logic as C `int sum=0; for(...) { sum += *p; p++;}`  The initialization to zero is necessary *only* because we want to use instructions like `add` that depend on the old value<sup>1</sup>.

---

Footnote 1: If you're optimizing for code-size, you could use `lodsw` and `add dx, ax` because `lodsw` increases `si` by 2.  And of course you'd always use `xor eax,eax` instead of `mov ax,0` to zero AX: despite appearances, CPUs special case that zeroing idiom to microarchitecturally *not* have an input dependency on the old value of the register.

Not so for `xor ax,ax`; that only saves code size but doesn't zero the full register so doesn't get special-cased by modern CPUs.  But if you're programming for a pre-386 CPU then you would just use `xor ax,ax` anyway; it doesn't do out-of-order exec the the input dependency doesn't matter: `x ^ x` is always zero regardless of the value.

---

> do we have to initialise the general purpose registers as we use to initialise the variables in C# programming?

Pretty much yes; registers in asm only need as much initialization as variables in high-level languages: at least once before the first read, unless they're incoming function args.

C/C++/C# variables whose first use will be write-only don't *need* to be initialized when declared.  (Although in modern C++ and C# style, you usually wait until the first assignment to declare them at all.)

You can think of registers as limited space for a few local variables, and/or scratch space for computation of temporaries.

And as Michael Petch commented, registers you *don't* use can be left untouched.